# Update csv value using executescript processor fails in apache-nifi

Tags: python, csv, apache-nifi

I try to read from a flowfile and update a record value using default value in csv. To that I have used `ExecuteScript` processor with following python code in it.

```
import sys
import re
import traceback
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil
from java.lang import Class
from java.io import BufferedReader
from java.io import InputStreamReader
from java.io import OutputStreamWriter

flowfile = session.get()
record = flowfile.getAttribute('record_type')

if record == '0':
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile,'record_type', 'NEW_USER')
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
elif record == '1':
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile,'record_type', 'OLD_USER')
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
else:
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile,'record_type', 'IGNORE')
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()

writer.flush()
writer.close()
reader.close()
```

My csv looks like

```
id,record_type
1,0
2,1
3,2
4,0
```

Result should be :

```
id,record_type
1,NEW_USER
2,OLD_USER
3,IGNORE
4,NEW_USER
```

I get following error :

> AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getAttribute' in
>   script at line number 13

It says `record = flowfile.getAttribute('record_type')` this is wrong..

I have no idea how to solve this as I am not good with `python`.

Comment: ExecuteScript processes the whole file (not by record). getAttribute returns attribute (like filename) and not the content. To change content use `flowFile.write` function. Search the inet for `nifi python cookbook` and look at the examples.

Comment: @daggett thanks for the suggestion. But still I dont understand how to get a value to compare.

Comment: If you are not good in python, maybe better to use record processing. Check the UpdateRecord processor.

Comment: @daggett Yes, I have used `UpdateRecord` processor, but having issue with replacing multiple values in one step as described in the question.

Comment: You have record-based `if` and I think it's possible to use UpdateRecord in your case. I could show how to do groovy script for your case.. (I'm bad in python also)

Comment: @daggett at the moment, anything would be a great help. I can get help from a fellow developer for groovy. so please post it. If it solves the issue, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that,s not python, but according to comment from author could be groovy.

use ExecuteGroovyScript processor with following code:

```groovy
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def map = [
    '0': 'NEW_USER',
    '1': 'OLD_USER',
]

ff.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){w->
        rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){r->
            int rowNum = 0
            //iterate lines from input stream and split each with coma
            r.splitEachLine( ',' ){row->
                if(rowNum>0){
                    //if not a header line then substitute value using map
                    row[1] = map[ row[1] ] ?: 'IGNORE'
                }
                //join and write row to output writer
                w << row.join(',') << '\n'
                rowNum++
            }
        }
    }
}

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as it solved my issue.

Comment: This is sub question, if we want to compare `string`, what kind of modification do we need to do for this?

Comment: In this script everything strings (except rowNum) even it contains numbers. `'0'` is a string.

Comment: I have tried it with a column defined as **use string from headers** but its not working as expected as earlier sample.

Comment: You mean you want to assess column by name from header and not by number?

Comment: Yes, I think so. as this doesnt solve my new question.

Comment: Please provide more details if you are not sure. Or ask a new question..

Comment: No, its similar, same data in the column. 0 and 1. Replace them with INCOME,PAYMENTS. I have tried this, but it always goes to IGNORE state.

Comment: I think better to ask a new question, so you'll be able to share the code.

Comment: Posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910020/update-csv-value-using-executescript-processor-fails-in-apache-nifi-using-groovy