# Update csv value using executescript processor fails in apache-nifi using groovy

Tags: csv, groovy, apache-nifi

This question is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850203/update-csv-value-using-executescript-processor-fails-in-apache-nifi)

Above solution solved my problem, Now I tried to connect this into a flow coming from `QueryRecord` processor.

Here this `QueryRecord` divide my flowfile into two streams. Lets say `customers` and `suppliers`. And `ExecuteGroovyScript` is used to add `ORDER` and `COMPLAINT`.

Sample csv :

```
id,record_type
1,0
2,0
3,1
```

So result should be :

```
id,record_type
1,ORDER
2,ORDER
3,COMPLAINT
```

Actual result just placed default `'IGNORE'` value.

`QueryRecord` configurations
[image: QueryRecord Configuration]

`QueryRecord` csv write schema.
[image: CSV writter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to update the field value simply, then use `UpdateRecord` processor.

When you input the text as follows:

```
id,record_type
1,0
2,0
3,1
```

then setting the record reader to `CSVReader` with the option `Schema Access Strategy` to the `Use String Fields From Header`. The writer is not a concern. The `UpdateRecord` processor properties look like this:

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/record_type                ${field.value:replace('0','ORDER'):replace('1','COMPLAINT')}
```

This will give your expected result.